# Table with dynamic number of rows in phpword

Tags: php, rows, phpword

Is it possible to create a table with dynamic rows?

I need to create a table based on array, but I do not know the size of the array at startup.

I saw something like this:

```
$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor($myfqfilenamehere);
$tags = $templateProcessor->getVariables();
foreach($tags as $tag){
    $templateProcessor->setValue($tag, "a value here");
}
```

But I don't know if its what I need.